# Problems with \pgfplotsset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I usually work on my computer but by strange reasons I have to work in the other one. The following code worked right before but in the new computer doesn't work. I have got a lot of error messages I don't understand (my knowledge about latex is poor).

I have got installed basic-MiKTeX-2.9.7269-x64 and Texmaker 5.0.3. in windows 10.
The code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-11.56,
xmax=11.56,
ymin=-8.5,
ymax=4.5,
xtick={-11,-10,...,11},
ytick={-8,-7,...,4},]
\draw [line width=2pt] (-9.86,-3.89)-- (-9.48,-3.71);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-2.42,1.25)-- (-3.62,-3.99);
\draw [line width=2pt] (8.36,-3.93)-- (7.84,2.07);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-6.9,1.43) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-6.74,1.86) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-5.24,-1.51) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-5.08,-1.08) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (0.94,-2.59) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (1.1,-2.16) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.56,1.79) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (2.72,2.22) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-9.86,-3.89) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-9.7,-3.46) node {$E$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-9.48,-3.71) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-9.32,-3.28) node {$F$};
\draw[color=black] (-9.46,-3.84) node {$f$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-2.42,1.25) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-2.26,1.68) node {$G$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.62,-3.99) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-3.46,-3.56) node {$H$};
\draw[color=black] (-3.26,-1.06) node {$g$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (8.36,-3.93) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (8.52,-3.5) node {$I$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (7.84,2.07) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (8,2.5) node {$J$};
\draw[color=black] (8.48,-0.66) node {$h$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error are:

```
line 50 ! Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }. <inserted text> \par \end{axis}
line 50 ! Paragraph ended before \pgfmathfloatparse@@ was complete. <to be read again> \par \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <recently read> } \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra \else. <argument> ...\pgfplots@stored@current@data \else \pgfplots@stored@plotlist@... \end{axis}
line 50 ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pgfplots@visphase@names \end{axis}
line 50 ! Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }. <inserted text> \par \end{axis} 
line 50 ! Paragraph ended before \pgfmathfloatparse@@ was complete. <to be read again> \par \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <recently read> } \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra \else. <argument> ...\pgfplots@stored@current@data \else     \pgfplots@stored@plotlist@... \end{axis}
line 50 ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pgfplots@visphase@names \end{axis} 
line 50 ! Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }. <inserted text> \par \end{axis} 
line 50 ! Paragraph ended before \pgfmathfloatparse@@ was complete. <to be read again> \par \end{axis} 
line 50 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <recently read> } \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra \else. <argument> ...\pgfplots@stored@current@data \else \pgfplots@stored@plotlist@... \end{axis}
line 50 ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pgfplots@visphase@names \end{axis}
line 50 ! Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }. <inserted text> \par \end{axis}
line 50 ! Paragraph ended before \pgfmathfloatparse@@ was complete. <to be read again> \par \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. <recently read> } \end{axis}
line 50 ! Extra \else. <argument> ...\pgfplots@stored@current@data \else \pgfplots@stored@plotlist@... \end{axis}
```

And there are a lot more.

I have been looking for some solution in a lot of forums but I have seen no solution for it.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works fine for me no errors

Comment: I am sure that it likely works in other computer. My aim is how to solve the errors I get. I don't know if they are related to a package of miktex... I want to solve them.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I think is the newest version.

Comment: Confirmed, works in TeXLive 2017, fails in TeXLive 2019. Maybe you should report this? I suspect *pgf*, but I could be worng.

Comment: @Rmano It is the syntax for circles. This has been mentioned in https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/. A perhaps simpler fix, though, is to use the non-deprecated syntax for circles.

Comment: For the record: The "problem" was fixed in PGFPlots v1.17. Thus, your code works perfectly fine again.

Answer (score 8):

I just answered a very similar answer, and the problem is always the same: you are using the deprecated syntax for circles, `circle(<radius>)`, but are supposed to use `circle[radius=<radius>]`, which fixes the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-11.56,
xmax=11.56,
ymin=-8.5,
ymax=4.5,
xtick={-11,-10,...,11},
ytick={-8,-7,...,4},]
\draw [line width=2pt] (-9.86,-3.89)-- (-9.48,-3.71);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-2.42,1.25)-- (-3.62,-3.99);
\draw [line width=2pt] (8.36,-3.93)-- (7.84,2.07);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-6.9,1.43) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-6.74,1.86) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-5.24,-1.51) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-5.08,-1.08) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (0.94,-2.59) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (1.1,-2.16) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.56,1.79) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (2.72,2.22) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-9.86,-3.89) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-9.7,-3.46) node {$E$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-9.48,-3.71) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-9.32,-3.28) node {$F$};
\draw[color=black] (-9.46,-3.84) node {$f$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-2.42,1.25) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-2.26,1.68) node {$G$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (-3.62,-3.99) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (-3.46,-3.56) node {$H$};
\draw[color=black] (-3.26,-1.06) node {$g$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (8.36,-3.93) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (8.52,-3.5) node {$I$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (7.84,2.07) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (8,2.5) node {$J$};
\draw[color=black] (8.48,-0.66) node {$h$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that [this issue has been reported](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/232/) but using the non-deprecated syntax also solves it.

Comment: Great!!! The solution of `circle[radius=<radius>]` works. We have got no error message and it compiles right. All my thanks you  @Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks,  @Schrödinger's cat.