# Strange scaling issue with circles in tikz/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am suddenly having a strange issue with circles within an axis environment. Any circles drawn inside an axis become weirdly stretched, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-2,ymax=2,axis equal]
    \node[fill=black,inner sep=3pt] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The issue persists even with the `axis equal image` option, and, weirdly, it seems that no matter what the bounds on the x-axis are, the drawn path does not "fit" into the coordinate system. On the other hand, the `circle` command works properly outside of an axis environment. Also, the `arc` command draws proper circles both in and outside of an axis environment (and with using axis coordinates and units), but I would obviously prefer to use the simpler syntax.

I should mention that I only have a single PC with this issue; my other computer compiles the exact same file properly. They are both running MiKTeX v. 2.9.7300 and have pgfplots v. 1.16.

I cannot say exactly when this issue appeared, but it should be within the last two months or so. It might be related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524076), but I cannot say.

Comment: I did not read the question carefully enough, sorry. You seem to have found an issue. There is [a patch underway](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/832#issuecomment-584484929), not sure though if it also fixes this issue.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No problem, thanks for trying to figure it out!

Comment: If you load `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` then a temporary workaround is `\draw let \p1=($(1,0)-(0,0)$) in (0,0) circle[radius=\x1];`. This will draw a circle of radius 1 in axis units.

Comment: I have explicitly verified that this issue will get fixed by applying [this patch](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/832#issuecomment-584484929) to `pgfplots.paths.code.tex`.